# Name or service not known error Varnish 5.2

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I have two web servers"for lab purpose ", they have the same web page. I also installed varnish  to do  round_robin and other kind of balance methods. 
But when I put the whole address of my web service"10.0.0.252/blog", my varnish return this error:Backend host '"10.0.0.253/blog"' 
**Name or service not known**

```
import directors;    # load the directors

backend server1 {
    .host = "10.0.0.253/blog";
}
backend server2 {
    .host = "10.0.0.252/blog";
}

sub vcl_init {
    new bar = directors.round_robin();
    bar.add_backend(server1);
    bar.add_backend(server2);
}

sub vcl_recv {
    # send all traffic to the bar director:
    set req.backend_hint = bar.backend();
}
```

If I put put just the web server address "10.0.0.252" the varnish start without error, but how I will define my page ? and other question please, I need to do any configuration in the side of my web server ?  in the apache or anything ? 
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`.host` takes an IP or domain name, so:

```
backend server1 {
    .host = "10.0.0.253";
}
backend server2 {
    .host = "10.0.0.252";
}
```

If you want to prepend "/blog" to all your requests, add

```
set req.url = "/blog" + req.url;
```

at the beginning of ``vcl_recv.

To check where the request went and with what url, add this to your VCL:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.http.used = beresp.backend.ip + bereq.url;
}
```

Also, look at the output of `varnishlog -g request` as you issue a request. You'll have a lot of info there.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply,  one last question, I have a client connected into this proxy and the servers are also connected into the proxy. To test i should open the proxy ip + the URL and should redirect me for one of the two web servers ?thank you again

Comment: add this to your vcl:
  sub vcl_backend_response {
       set beresp.http.used = beresp.backend.ip + bereq.url;
  }
and you'll get the IP of the server and what URL was sent to it in the "used" header of your response

Comment: Buddy, Just to see if I understood you, my varnish should be like this:

Comment: import directors;    
# load the directors


vcl 4.0;

sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.http.used = beresp.backend.ip + bereq.url;
}

backend server1 {
    .host = "10.0.0.253";
}
backend server2 {
    .host = "10.0.0.252";
}

sub vcl_init {
    new bar = directors.round_robin();
    bar.add_backend(server1);
    bar.add_backend(server2);
}

sub vcl_recv {
   set req.url = "/blog" + req.url;
    set req.backend_hint = bar.backend();
}

Answer (score 0):

```
import directors;    
# load the directors


vcl 4.0;

sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.http.used = beresp.backend.ip + bereq.url;
}

backend server1 {
    .host = "10.0.0.253";
}
backend server2 {
    .host = "10.0.0.252";
}

sub vcl_init {
    new bar = directors.round_robin();
    bar.add_backend(server1);
    bar.add_backend(server2);
}

sub vcl_recv {
   set req.url = "/blog" + req.url;
    set req.backend_hint = bar.backend();
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what it should look like.